# Use Terraform to deploy MySQL 8.0 in AWS Aurora V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I'm attempting to deploy a serverless MySQL 8.0 service using AWS Aurora V2 using Terraform.

Terraform details (not on latest version, but should be compatible with latest AWS provider version):

```
Terraform v0.15.4
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.12.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/consul v2.15.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault v3.5.0
```

Here's the relevant `main.tf` file:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "database" {
  cluster_identifier      = var.cluster_identifier
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.db_subnet_group.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  engine_mode             = "serverless"
  enable_http_endpoint    = var.enable_http_endpoint
  master_username         = var.master_username
  master_password         = random_password.rng.result
  database_name           = var.name
  backup_retention_period = var.backup_retention_period
  skip_final_snapshot     = var.skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection     = var.deletion_protection
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.0"

  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = var.max_capacity
    min_capacity = var.min_capacity
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      engine_version,
      availability_zones,
      master_username,
      master_password,
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
    Name        = var.name
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  identifier         = "${var.cluster_identifier}-serverless"
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.database.id
  instance_class     = "db.serverless"
  engine             = aws_rds_cluster.database.engine
  engine_version     = aws_rds_cluster.database.engine_version
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "db_subnet_group" {
  name       = "${var.cluster_identifier}-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
  }
}

resource "random_password" "rng" {
  length  = 16
  special = false

  keepers = {
    cluster_identifier = var.cluster_identifier
  }
}
```

The above file was originally a serverless MySQL 5.7 service using Aurora V1. I modified this existing `main.tf` file using these resources:

- GitHub issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/24349
- Terraform docs for [`aws_rds_cluster`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster)
- Terraform docs for [`aws_rds_cluster_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster_instance)

The `terraform plan` goes fine. When running `terraform apply` this error is present:

```
module.aurora.aws_rds_cluster.database: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating RDS cluster: InvalidParameterValue: The engine mode serverless you requested is currently unavailable.
│   status code: 400, request id: 060f8bce-4bc4-4462-9735-78495ecaf308
│ 
│   with module.aurora.aws_rds_cluster.database,
│   on modules/aws/rds/main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "database":
│    1: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "database" {
│ 
╵
```

I can't infer much from this error, I'm guessing something isn't supporting this since the AWS provider `v4.12.0` was released yesterday. I assume it could also be the version of Terraform itself, but again, I believe Terraform v0.15.4 is compatible with the v4.12.0 of the AWS provider.

My main goal is to switch the service from MySQL 5.7 serverless to MySQL 8.0 serverless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `engine_mode` for Aurora Serverless 2 is [`provisioned`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster#serverlessv2_scaling_configuration-argument-reference), not `serverless`.

```
    engine_mode               = "provisioned"
```

Comment: Hmm... I'll try this out next. Do you have a link to any documentation that supports this?

Comment: Making this change allowed deploy pipeline pass and looking at the resources in AWS, it looks like it did deploy a MySQL 8.0 service with Aurora V2. If anyone could find and link the docs that mention this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @MicahParks thanks. Sadly I have no link. It's not documented from what I see for now.

Comment: Well thank you so much for the help anyways. Probably wouldn't have guessed the `engine_mode` was `provisioned` since it's marketed as "Amazon Aurora Serverless v2". To be clear and so nobody is mislead: making this change still uses a "serverless" product. Not sure why the `engine_mode` needs to be `provisioned` though.

Comment: @MicahParks docs mention it here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster#serverlessv2_scaling_configuration-argument-reference

Comment: Thanks for the link. This link is regarding `serverlessv2_scaling_configuration` only being valid when `engine_mode` is `provisioned`. I think this is sufficient, because the I think the only way to provision Aurora V2 is with `serverlessv2_scaling_configuration`. But if anyone else has link to documentation that shows how Aurora V2 requires the `engine_mode` `provisioned`, those links would be good as well.